# RelativeLayout Background Transparent

Tags: android, background, transparent, android-relativelayout

I have a Relative Layout with some views like ImageView, TextView etc inside it. There are also unused spaces. I only want the unused spaces to be transparent, not the Views. But whatever I do like set alpha, it makes the whole thing inside the Relative Layout change.
Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"

    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"

        >




            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:id="@+id/rl"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                >







                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/profilepicBlog"
                    android:layout_width="54dp"
                    android:layout_height="54dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                    android:padding="6dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/defimg"
                    app:civ_border_color="#2a30a3"
                    app:civ_border_width="1dp"

                    />



                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/post_username"
                    android:layout_width="193dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="74dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                    android:text="UserName"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
                    android:textColor="#4d5459"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/tools"
                    android:layout_width="37dp"
                    android:layout_height="34dp"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
                    android:rotation="90"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_image"

                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/usertime"
                    android:layout_width="193dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/post_username"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/post_username"
                    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#737377"
                    />


            </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

As you can see, there is a cardview, inside which there is a linear layout, inside which there is the relative layout. The relative layout contains different views. I want to make the unused parts in relative layout transparent so that when the cardview is retrieved in recyclerview in an activity, only the views are visible.

Comment: Did you try setting  `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` in `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Yes, I tried. Please check the updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add  this to your CardView's layout: `card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"`

You don't need to set the other background layouts to transparent.